# How to always automatically show the label of a container element in the backend of TYPO3?

Tags: typo3

SEE SOLUTION BELOW -->

---

I often use [Container Content Elements](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/container) for flexible content creation in TYPO3. The implementation is simple and easy as described [here](https://github.com/b13/container/blob/master/README.md).
After adding a container in the backend I would prefer to see automatically the label of the container so I do not have to set a title.

This would help to show what type of container element is used in the backend.

This is the container without setting a title:
[image: Container without title]

And this is the container with a title – I would prefer to set it always automatically from the label field:
[image: Container with title]

Any idea if this is possible?

---

SOLUTION (Thanks to Julian):

Use "setBackendTemplate" in the container registration in:

```
VENDOR/Module/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/tt_content.php

    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\B13\Container\Tca\Registry::class)->configureContainer(
        (
            new \B13\Container\Tca\ContainerConfiguration(
                'b13-2cols-with-header-container', // CType
                '2 Column Container With Header', // label
                'Some Description of the Container', // description
                [
                    // ...
                ] // grid configuration
            )
        )
        // set your own template for BE
        ->setBackendTemplate('EXT:Module/Resources/Private/Templates/Container/Example.html')
    );
```

The content of the backend-template-file located in

```
    EXT:Module/Resources/Private/Templates/Container/Example.html
```

could be:

```
<html
   mlns:f="http://typo3.org/ns/TYPO3/CMS/Fluid/ViewHelpers"
    xmlns:container="http://typo3.org/ns/B13/Container/ViewHelpers"
   data-namespace-typo3-fluid="true"
>

    ## with cType
    Container: <strong>{CType}</strong><br>

    ## with translation
    <f:translate key="LLL:EXT:sitepackage_example/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:container.{CType}" />

    <f:format.raw>{tx_container_grid}</f:format.raw>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily set your own template via `setBackendTemplate()` for each of your container ([Documetation](https://github.com/b13/container/blob/master/README.md#methods-of-the-containerconfiguration-object)):

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\B13\Container\Tca\Registry::class)->configureContainer(
    (
        new \B13\Container\Tca\ContainerConfiguration(
            'b13-2cols-with-header-container', // CType
            '2 Column Container With Header', // label
            'Some Description of the Container', // description
            [
                // ...
            ] // grid configuration
        )
    )
    // set your own template for BE
    ->setBackendTemplate('EXT:sitepackage_example/Resources/Private/Templates/Container/2ColumnsHeader.html')
);
```

Comment: Thanks, Julian! But is there a basic example how the backend template is built? I tried with the same as the frontend template but I did not succeed. And [here](https://github.com/b13/container-example) is also no example available.

Comment: Default of EXT:container is `EXT:container/Resources/Private/Templates/Container.html`. So, that should be an example ;)

Comment: Super, works like a charm! But one thing: The defined label (defined in tt_content.php) is not available in the backend Fluid template, isn't it? I am only able to get the CType with {CType}.

Comment: IMO it's possible to use Fluid within Fluid calls, like: `<f:translate key="LLL:EXT:sitepackage_example/Resources/Private/Language/locallang.xlf:container.{CType}" />`. Sadly, it's not possible to access the TCA-value's label.

Comment: This is a quite good solution as it then also works with multiple languages in the backend, thanks!